# Margin moves div outside window

Tags: html, css

I the following html and css:

```
<div class="foo"></div>

<style>
.foo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 20px
}
</style>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6nbvmp4/)

The Problem is the `margin: 20px`. Its shifting the whole div to the right and bottom and outside the window. I would expect it to reduce the width of the div, such that the whole element takes 100% of the windows width.

Somehow I cant get this to work. I found solutions, but all of them dont use the fixed position.

Comment: Add padding in place of margin

Comment: What are you trying to do with the margin: 20px? I don't understand the end goal, it's resolving exactly as your defining? specify what kind of margin you want?

Comment: I want the background to be visible at the area of the margin.

Comment: Just check what your support is.. use calc if you don't have to support many mobile devices or old browsers... otherwise just create a wrapper div with max-width and padding, or use border: 20px solid white; ;)

Comment: I had a wrapper before, the point was here that i wanted to remove it. thanks for all the support:) i try now all solutions and figure out which fits the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
.foo {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/a6nbvmp4/1/

**EDIT:**

Another possible solution without `calc`, but with `box-shadow`:

```
.foo {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px white inset;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/a6nbvmp4/6/

Comment: is this calc supported by old browsers?

Comment: It's not supported on Android Stock browser, I know that :(

Comment: Supported by IE9+, and all modern browsers. Not Android :( https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following change in your css.

```css
.foo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/a6nbvmp4/4/)

Comment: here the problem seems to remain at the bottom.

Comment: I think its not working for me, since I need the height and width property.

Comment: You need to show the background behind this red div?
check the updated fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/a6nbvmp4/7/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just assign a position offset of 20px to all 4 sides?

```
.foo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brimwd/72rbgr85/